# xctk ColorPicker in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, color-picker

I have a `DataGrid` with 2 cells but I want to add another cell with a `ColorPicker`:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtg" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="200"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="50,20,0,15"
              SelectionChanged="rowSelect" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="false" RowEditEnding="cellc">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBFBFBF" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="n1" IsReadOnly="false" Binding="{Binding n1}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="n2"  IsReadOnly="false"  Binding="{Binding n2}" 
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

class to fill cells:

```
 public class data
{
    public int n1 { get; set; }
    public int n2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need a property of type `System.Windows.Media.Color` to your `Data` class:

```
public Color DataColor { get; set; }
```

Now you need to add the Extended WPF Toolkit namespace to your view:

```
xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
```

You can define a column of your data grid with a custom template by using the `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Just add such a template with a `ColorPicker` and bind the defined property. Here is an example:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- ... -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Color">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ColorCellTemplate">
                    <xctk:ColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding DataColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         DisplayColorAndName="True" UsingAlphaChannel="False"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- ... -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks! And another thing: how can I get the color selected of specefic colorpick cell?

Comment: Just get the color by binding the Color-property of the picker to your data objects.

Comment: sorry but I don't know what even use to catch the ColorPicker selected, I have tryied with editrowending but don't throw the event when the color is selected. I want to know when the color was selected at specific row.

Comment: If a new color is selected the bound property changes. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties Simply extend the setter of your property like required.